# active works but not focus or target using css

Tags: html, css

So below is my code. The "active" command in the css block works since when clicking on the div it changes color but when letting go of the click its border should become red as stated in the "target" command in the css block but it doesn't. Ideas?

```
<html>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
.svar-grid {
  margin: 20px;
}

.svar-grid .svar {

    padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
    margin-top:20px;
  width:100%;
  border:2px solid black;
  border-radius:10px;
  background:yellowgreen;
}


.svar-grid .svar:active {

    padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
    margin-top:20px;
  width:100%;
  border:2px solid black;
  border-radius:10px;
  background:green;
}

.svar-grid .svar:target {

    padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
    margin-top:20px;
  width:100%;
  border:2px solid red;
  border-radius:10px;
  background:green;
}

</style>

<html>   
 <div>
        <div class="svar-grid">
          <div class="svar"><h4>Testing</h4></div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I think you are confused at what target does, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `:focus`.

https://jsfiddle.net/s0L716zu/

HTML

```
    <div class="svar-grid">
      <div class="svar" tabindex="-1"><h4>Testing</h4></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.svar-grid .svar:focus {  ....   }
```

As you can see I added `tabindex="-1"` to the div because a div is not naturally focusable. Giving it -1 tabinde makes is focusable

Here is what `:target` is supposed to do https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target,  It is meant to be used with the URL

I am not sure why you need focus on the div or if there is any interaction with it. But if there are interaction with the div, you should probably use `button` or an anchor tag depending on its usage

Answer (score 2):

`:target` applies to elements with an `id` attribute which matches the string that appears after the first `#` character in the URL.  This is that that when you link to something specific on a page, it can be highlighted to draw the eye to it.

Since the element doesn't have an `id`, the `:target` pseudo-class cannot apply.

---

`:focus` applies to elements that have the focus. Clicking on an element will, generally, give it the focus … but only if the element is focusable in the first place.

The point of the focus is so that when interacting with a user interface without using a pointing device (e.g. a mouse, trackpad or touchscreen) you can move between interactive controls via some other mechanism (e.g. pressing the tab key). Then you can trigger (e.g. by pressing Enter) the focused element.

This is only useful if the element does something when triggered (e.g. if it is a link or a button). A div doesn't, by default, do anything when triggered. It is a generic *container*.

You can add interactivity to an element with JavaScript (`addEventListener`) and you can mark the element as being interactive by using the `tabindex` attribute … but you should usually pick a different element (like `<button>`) instead.